# La sentencia sqli_query no se ejecuta pero la consulta sql si se ejecuta

Tags: php, subconsultas

Envió el  error que sale al ejecutar el programa 
esta conectado (este aparece comprobando que si se conecta a la base de datos)

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\seccionUsuarios\class\class.php on line 29

este es el código

```
<?php   
    session_start();
    class Conectar
    {
        public  function conexion1()
        {
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","checa","12345","registro_de_usuarios");
            if($con="true" )
            {
                echo "esta conectado";

            }
            return $con;
        }

    }
    class Trabajo
    {
        public function logueo()
        {
            $conexion = new Conectar();
            $con=$conexion->conexion1();
            $user =$_POST['user'];
            $pas_js =$_POST['pass'];
            /**$pass_php =md5($_POST["pass"]);**/
            $sql = "select * from usuarios where user = ".$user." and pas_js=".$pas_js."";
            /**echo "$sql";
            exit;**/
            $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $consulta =mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
            if( mysql_num_rows($consulta)=="0")
            {
                echo "Los datos ingresados no existen en la base de datos";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Si existen";
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema, y más grave, es la mezcla de instrucciones `mysqli_*` y `mysql_*`, estas últimas ya obsoletas y removidas en PHP 7. Cambia las dos lineas con ese problema en la clase `Trabajo` por:

```
$consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0)
```

`mysqli_num_rows()` devuelve un dato entero. No va a fallar esta parte del programa si lo comparas a una cadena, ya que PHP acepta comparar enteros con su respectivo valor string, pero como ya sabes qué tipo va a devolver siempre, entonces es buena práctica comparar los datos con lo que en realidad son, en este caso enteros con enteros. 
[EDIT] Esta instruccion tiene como parametros el objeto de la consulta, en este caso `$res`.

Otro problema (que es la causa del error que describes) está en la clase `Conectar`, la variable `$con` toma el valor de un objeto, o bien `false` si falla la conexión. En el `if($con="true" )` el operador de comparación es `==`, no `=` que es de asignación. Y los datos booleanos en PHP NO se representan como cadenas con comillas. Tendrías que escribirlo como: `if($con == true)`. Sin embargo PHP evalúa como `true` cualquier objeto, así que es suficiente cambiar esa línea por:

```
if($con)
```

También tienes la consulta mal, faltan las comillas en la evaluación. Debe ser:

```
$sql = "select * from usuarios where user='".$user."' and pas_js='".$pas_js."'";
```

Nota: Esa consulta es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. En un futuro cuando domines un poco más del tema, investigar sobre la [inyeccion SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Gracias paso la primera parte de mysqli_query y ahora no se ejecuta mysqli_num_rows y elimine la sentencia resultado =mysqli_tetch_assoc()

Comment: y solo coloque  if( mysqli_num_rows(&res)==0);

Comment: @ivancheca ya lo corregí en el código, `mysqli_num_rows()` evalúa el objeto de consulta devuelto, no el resultado de `mysqli_fetch_*`

Comment: me aparece este error (
85/5000
Advertencia: mysqli_num_rows () espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli_result, booleano dado en)

Comment: @ivancheca El problema es que mysql te está devolviendo `false` porque no está bien construida la consulta SQL, le faltan las comillas simples a los datos. Agregué esa corrección en la respuesta.

Comment: Advertencia: mysqli_num_rows () espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli_result, booleano dado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ seccionUsuarios \ class \ class.php en la línea 31  . este es el error que me sale

Comment: muchas gracias si me resulto te agradezco aepotugal espero seguir contando contigo soy nuevo en este lenguaje. como haría para contactarte de nuevo si necesito de nuevo tu ayuda